# Cannot add a watcher to my test scripts with vue-utils

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-test-utils

I am trying to add a watcher in my "test" script I defined in the package.json.

What I want to achieve is quite simple : I want the command line "npm run test" to be executed each time I modify a file that ends with .spec.js in the tests/FrontEnd directory.

What I get when I run "npm run test" are the following lines :

[image]

This is how I've modified the script to get the watcher :

> ```
>     "test": "mocha-webpack --webpack-config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js --require tests/Frontend/setup.js tests/Frontend/**/*.spec.js --watch"
> ```

Everything works when I remove the --watch at the end of my script.

My dependencies versions are here :

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.10.1",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.32",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "expect": "^25.1.0",
        "fibers": "^4.0.2",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "jsdom": "^16.2.1",
        "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "mocha": "^4.0.1",
        "mocha-webpack": "^0.7.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "preload-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
        "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
        "webpack": "^4.42.0"
    },
```

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an incompatibility of the `mocha-webpack` plugin version you're using and the `webpack` plugin you're using. The `0.7.0` version of `mocha-webpack` is written for an older webpack plugin system, and as such might not work with the newer one. In the webpack version you're using `4.20.0` (approx), the `chunk` property does not have the property/accessor of `modules`, and that's where you see the error.

And this code path is run only in watch mode (from what I was able to gather from that version's codebase), so this didn't happen when you didn't provide `--watch`.

Try upgrading the `mocha-webpack` plugin to the latest stable version.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately going back to webpack 3 didn't solve the issue.. Now I have another problem. "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'optimization'."

I've tried to add UfligyJsPlugin to solve this without success..

Thanks for your help !

Comment: webpack config between v3 and v4 is different, so the error you see is because of that. Did you try upgrading mocha-webpack though?